# invitation letter for UK short-term visa

Tags: visas, uk, study, invitation-letters

i want to apply the UK short term study visa (up to 11 months),on the web said that "you shouldn't pay for accomodation and travel until you get the visa"

i wrote down my friend's address on the visa web cause i plan to stay there.do my friend need to make an invitation letter for me stated that i will stay there during the course period?

Comment: Are you going to pay your friend for staying in their house for the 11 months ? If not, you better get an invitation letter from your friend as they are paying(sort of) for your accommodation.

Comment: if i will pay my friend, will i need a rental agreement or something like that?

Comment: According to the rules you cannot use a short term study visa. https://www.gov.uk/study-visit-visa  You need to check what is the correct type of visa you require. And 11 months isn't short term.

Comment: @DumbCoder A stay of up to 11 months is permitted if studying an English language course.